# Export sent email campaigns to csv

Tags: exm

Could you please help with my problem I'm facing now.

I'm using Sitecore 9 update 1.

The requirement is to add a button to the Sent Email Campaign detail page named "Export To CSV". After the user clicked on this button, a CSV file will be generated with data like clicks, date, name/email address, engagement value.

I added an action item to `/sitecore/client/Applications/ECM/Component/Actions/Message/Column/Message` that is already appearing in the email campaign detail page. What should I do next?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who need the answer.
Add action item to this folder "**/sitecore/client/Applications/ECM/Component/Actions/General/Column/General**" for "**Sent email campaigns**" page a another action item to this folder "**/sitecore/client/Applications/ECM/Component/Actions/Message/Column/Message**" for **email campign detail** page

Edit these files

**\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\ECM\EmailCampaign.Client\Pages\Messages.js**

on the function inside **this.MessageList.on('change:selectedItem'** **if (selectedItem.get('sent') > 0)**: edit the parameter of enableAction('[your new item id]', true)
add this code after that
//update report data service to get datasource to selected message

```
var dateRange = { dateTo: new Date(), dateFrom: new Date($(selectedItem.get('startDate'))[0].innerHTML) };
                        ReportDataService.set(_.extend({
                            managerRootId: sessionStorage.managerRootId,
                            messageId: selectedItem.get('itemId')
                        }, dateRange))
```

Get data from this.MessageList.get('selectedItem') and ReportDataService.get('totals')
export to csv file from javascript

**\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\ECM\EmailCampaign.Client\Pages\Messages\MessageBase.js**

add new action to initActions function
get data from this.MessageContext and ReportDataService.get('totals')
export to csv file from javascript